# Convert DSV to CSV

Tags: python, r, excel, csv

I have a .dsv file with a"}" delimiter and wanted to have a .csv or .txt file to be loaded on for data visualization. What is the quickest and easiest way to achieve the same? With small file size, it could be loaded onto an Excel sheet but my file size is more than 7 GB and would need more powerful tool.

Thanks

Comment: You could use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) and import your dsv to a dataframe and do all the manipulation you want.

Comment: Please see [ask]. General forum questions with multiple unrelated tags are off-topic on StackOverflow which is a Q&A site for **specific** code implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to load the data into R or python you can specify the separator manually.

**Python**

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.dsv", sep="}")
```

**R**

```r
library(readr)

df <- read_delim("data.dsv", delim = "}")
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to actual convert the file to csv you can do a find and replace using something like [sed](https://www.techradar.com/how-to/computing/apple/terminal-101-find-and-replace-using-sed-1305723). So replace `}` with `,`.